# R.java not generating while doing Android tutorial?

Tags: java, android, xml

So I'm working on the Android tutorial provided by android.com. However, when I get to the Adding Action Buttons portion, I try to use the code that supports Android 2.1 with support libraries and that seems to cause an error in the .xml file. I have the same .xml name, "main_activity_actions.xml" with the same exact code. I notcied that my R.java however, was able to generate whenever I took out

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

So, I'm not really sure what's wrong with this. My code is virtually the same throughout the tutorial up through this point.

Link for tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Entire Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Any errors in resource files?

Comment: because u are missing some xml resources somewhere .Check all is well.

Comment: R.java file will not generate if u have error in u r xml file check u r last modified xml file including menu also

Answer (score 1):

Are the support libraries added to the project? Right-click the project, Android Tools --> Add Support Libraries.

If that isn't the issue, you need to post more information. Post the build errors, there should be information in there related to why the R file could not be generated.

Comment: The thing is, I'm using support libraries to support Android 2.1 and over. I'm using the name space, app to use those support libraries. I defined the name space as

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

Comment: You need to use a different namespace when using a library as on the code above so this is correct.

Comment: Oh I see, did you make sure the support library was added to the project. Right click --> Android Tools --> Add Support Library

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer to my question which was pretty stupid. The wrong part about the .xml is that the resources did not exist such as the string action_search and the drawable ic_action_search, thus R.java could not be generated and I had no idea as to why. Thanks for all the help guys!