# Adding button to Action Bar causes R to not comple

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I am attempting to add a button to my action bar but when I add the xml it causes the R file to stop being generated breaking the entire application. I've been trying to follow Google's instructions (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/addtaskbutton"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_label"
        android:title="ab_addtask"
        android:visible="ifRoom"
   />

</menu>
```

And here is the only Java code where I reference the button

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.addtaskbutton:
        promptUserForInfo();
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: I don't think this is about the R programming language, so I'm going to edit and remove the tag.  Please roll back the edit if I am incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifRoom` is not a valid value for `android:visible` in your second item. Either change it to `android:visible="true"`, `android:visible="false"`, or `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` (what I expect you wanted).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the proper support libraries to your project? This is probably similar to the problem posted here:

[R.java not generating while doing Android tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038069/r-java-not-generating-while-doing-android-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Like Chase said in the comments under the question, If you are using Eclipse, go to the Project menu and select Clean.  The R.java file is auto generated so if you add a new action you need to regenerate R.java

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
```

This is the comment at the top of R.java